# Design of the Protobuf binary format: performance and varint

Tags: protocol-buffers

I need to design a binary format to save data from a scientific application. This data has to be encoded in a binary format that can't be easily read by any other application (it is a requirement by some of our clients). As a consequence, we decided to build our own binary format, its encoder and its decoder.

We got some inspiration from many binary format, including protobuf. One thing that puzzles me is the way protobuf encodes the length of embedded messages. According to https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding, the size of an embedded message is encoded at its very beginning as a varint.
But before we encode an embedded message, we don't know yet its size (think for instance of an embedded message that contains many integers encoded as varint). As a consequence, we need to encode the message entirely, before we write it to the disk so we know its size.
Imagine that this message is huge. As a consequence, it is very difficult to encode it in an efficient way. We could encode this size as a full int and seek back to this part of the file once the embedded message is written, but we loose the nice property of varints: you don't need to specify if you have a 32-bit or a 64-bit integer. So going back to Google's implementation using a varint:

Is there an implementation trick I am missing, or is this scheme likely to be inefficient for large messages?

Comment: For scientific data and large files, take also look at HDF5. Its performance is often better than protobuf if there is a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the correct way to do this is to write the message first, at the back of the buffer, and then prepend the size.  With proper buffer management, you can write the message in reverse.

That said, why write your own message format when you can just use protobuf?   It would be better to just use Protobuf directly and encrypt the file format.  That would be easy for you to use, and still be hard for other applications to read.

Comment: There are many reasons why I don't want to use protobuf. The main one being that I want something dynamic, with keys and types in the saved file, the way BSON and MessagePack work. Another reason is that I'll store arrays of uint16 (for gray scale images of 16-bit depth). The fact that protobuf does not have a uint16 type that always take 2 bytes does not help.

Comment: Then can I ask why you posted a question about Protobuf?  It seems out of place seeing as you want something with a very different wire format.

Comment: Because I want to steal the best ideas from different file formats. That's the reason I want to understand the rationale behind them, their advantages and their downsides.